# ggmap openstreetmap SCALE, no zoom necessary?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, coordinate-system

I am relatively new to map projections but believe I have understood how one could translate lat/lon to the map tile coordinates X and Y, which is nicely explained here:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

When requesting Google static maps, we need to supply a zoom value which makes sense to me.
However for the function get_openstreetmap(), I am quite puzzled on the scale parameter and how one could possibly translate scale to zoom. That seems impossible/difficult since zoom values are discrete integers and scale more or less continuous.
If scale->zoom is not done, how does the package project lat/lon to Y/X ?
I dug through the sources but the only function I could find was LonLat2XY() which also requires a zoom level.

What function performs the translation for OSM maps?